# How to prove that the lattice potential can be separated into two components in diatomic lattice?

Tags: solid-state-physics, potential-energy, electronic-band-theory

For a 1-D diatomic lattice with overall period $a$ and atoms $A$, $B$ placed at $\pm \frac{a}{4}(1-\delta)$, I am struggling to prove that $$ U_\frac{2\pi}{a} = \sin(\frac{\pi\delta}{2})(U^A_\frac{2\pi}{a}+U^B_\frac{2\pi}{a})-i\cos(\frac{\pi\delta}{2})(U^A_\frac{2\pi}{a}-U^B_\frac{2\pi}{a})\text{, where}$$ $$ U^{A, B}_\frac{2\pi}{a} = \frac{N}{V} \int_{\text{unit cell}} e^{-i(\frac{2\pi}{a}\cdot r)}U^{A,B}(r)\space dr.$$

A huge source of confusion is that I'm not quite sure what the $U^{A,B}(r)$ are supposed to represent. If they are contributions to the potential from $A, B$ respectively, shouldn't they simply superpose?

For context, I have proven everything in the below image thus far, and am struggling wtith 4.144/4.145:[image: Previous parts of problem]

Answer (score 0):

We define the Fourier coefficient of the full potential $U(x)$ to be
$$
U_{G}=\frac{N}{V}\int_{\textrm{unit cell}}e^{-iG x}U(x)\,dx\,.
$$
Now, we note that the potential can be written as a sum
$$
U(x) = U^A(x-a(1-\delta)/4)+U^B(x+a(1-\delta)/4)\,,
$$
where we have explicitly built in the positions of the two atoms in the basis. Then, the Fourier coefficient becomes
\begin{align*}
U_{G}&=\frac{N}{V}\int_{\textrm{unit cell}}e^{-iG x}U^A(x-a(1-\delta)/4)\,dx
+\frac{N}{V}\int_{\textrm{unit cell}}e^{-iG x}U^B(x+a(1-\delta)/4)\,dx
\\
&=
\frac{N}{V}\int_{\textrm{unit cell}}e^{-iG (x+a(1-\delta)/4)}U^A(x)\,dx
+\frac{N}{V}\int_{\textrm{unit cell}}e^{-iG (x-a(1-\delta)/4)}U^B(x)\,dx
\\
&=
e^{-iG a(1-\delta)/4}\frac{N}{V}\int_{\textrm{unit cell}}e^{-iG x}U^A(x)\,dx
+e^{iG a(1-\delta)/4}\frac{N}{V}\int_{\textrm{unit cell}}e^{-iG x}U^B(x)\,dx\,,
\end{align*}
which for $G=2\pi/a$ becomes
\begin{align*}
U_{2\pi/a}
&=
-ie^{i\pi\delta/2}\frac{N}{V}\int_{\textrm{unit cell}}e^{-iG x}U^A(x)\,dx
+ie^{-i\pi\delta/2}\frac{N}{V}\int_{\textrm{unit cell}}e^{-iG x}U^B(x)\,dx
\\
&=-ie^{i\pi\delta/2}U^A_{2\pi/a}+ie^{-i\pi\delta/2}U^B_{2\pi/a}
\,.
\end{align*}
This can then be written in terms of trigonometric functions as
\begin{align*}
U_{2\pi/a}
&=-i(\cos(\pi\delta/2)+i\sin(\pi\delta/2))U^A_{2\pi/a}
+i(\cos(\pi\delta/2)-i\sin(\pi\delta/2))U^B_{2\pi/a}
\\
&=\sin(\pi\delta/2)(U^A_{2\pi/a}+U^B_{2\pi/a})
+i\cos(\pi\delta/2)(U^B_{2\pi/a}-U^A_{2\pi/a})
\,.
\end{align*}
This is the same as the expression in the OP.

---

Now, my guess as to *why* you would want to do things in this way is to make it so that the dependence on the relative positions of the two atoms in the basis (parameterized by $\delta$) shows up explicitly in the expressions for the Fourier coefficients and therefore the energies, etc.  For instance, if the two atoms in the basis are the same, then $U^A(x)=U^B(x)$, in which case the expression becomes
\begin{align*}
U_{2\pi/a}
&=2\sin(\pi\delta/2)U^A_{2\pi/a}
\,,
\end{align*}
and so $\delta$ will explicitly parameterize the splitting that occurs when we take a monatomic lattice of lattice constant $a/2$ and create a diatomic lattice of lattice constant $a$ by moving every other atom by a small amount $\delta a/2$.